# ElasticSearch Nest Cross-Cluster Search C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to perform a cross-cluster search using Nest but I'm not being able to find a way.

Uri elasticNode = new Uri(elasticSearchUri);
ConnectionSettings nodeSettings = new ConnectionSettings(elasticNode).DefaultIndex(elasticIndexName);
ElasticClient elasticClient = new ElasticClient(nodeSettings);

Find no documentation about it as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [search across clusters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cross-cluster-search.html), first need to have at least one remote cluster configured

```cs
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://example.com:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var putSettingsResponse = client.Cluster.PutSettings(s => s
    .Persistent(d => d
        .Add("cluster.remote.cluster_two.seeds", new[] { "127.0.0.1:9300" })
        .Add("cluster.remote.cluster_two.skip_unavailable", true)
    )
);
```

This configures a cluster named `cluster_two` at `127.0.0.1:9300` (use the transport layer port).

Now, to search across both the cluster configured with the client and the remote cluster

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Index("index_name,cluster_two:index_name")
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

which searches across the index named `"index_name"` in the cluster at `http://example.com:9200` and the index named `"index_name"` in remote cluster at `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks for this I ended up being able to do it before I saw the response but that is correct, I ended up using  .Index(*:index_name) because I run multiply remote clusters.